# The tensor value are doubling automatically and I can't understand the reason

Tags: python, variables, return, tensor

So, there is a function call in a loop and I am keeping the tensor returned from the function in a variable but once the loop restarts the value in the tensor is automatically doubled. HOW?? Code explanation:

```
a=None
for loop:
    if a is not None:
        print("1")
        print(a)

    pred = non_max_suppression(pred, conf_thres, iou_thres, classes, agnostic_nms,a, 
    max_det=max_det)

    a=pred
    print("2")
    print(a)
```

After print statement "2" correct value is printed but after statement "1" *(after the loop starts again)* the value of first 4 out of 6 columns of the tensor doubles without any reason that I could understand.
and I have already checked the variable 'a', it is not getting manipulated anywhere else except here in this part so how is the value doubling automatically.

Comment: Can you add some more of your code? Is that function `tf.image.non_max_suppression`?

Comment: It's the yoloV5 non max suppression function for post-processing of the detections. but as far as I know, that is not important here. I can't understand how can the tensor 'a' value change(doubling) for the first four columns @maciek97x

Comment: I solved the issue by converting the tensor to a list and then back to the tensor above print("1") statement since only the value in the tensor changes in the loop (I don't know why??). This is the weirdest issue I faced in my life.